# Add broadFileSystemAccess capability to Unity+UWP

Tags: xaml, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am trying to add the [capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) named `broadFileSystemAccess` to our UWP application that is built ***with Unity*** and has no XAML markup. The documentation says to add the following to the app manifest, but no app manifest exists in the unity / visual studio project. Is this capability not possible on MRP, or are we doing something wrong?

This is what is supposed to be added to your *App package manifest*, but like I mentioned, we don't have one of those.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:uap4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4">
...
<Capabilities>
    <uap4:CustomCapability Name="CompanyName.customCapabilityName_PublisherID"/>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Hi, You can add capabilities as follows : **[PlayerSettingsWSA Capabilities](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Capabilities)** but If a capability is not in the list you must build your project with IL2CPP in order to output an app package manifest.

Comment: After the build you may have a file named `Package.appxmanifest`.

Comment: @loic.lopez Thank you for the help! I've found the file now.

Comment: I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @loic.lopez Sure thing! One last question if you happen to know. Is there any way to ensure that this manifest file has that capability every time a build is made without manually re-adding it? Or do I need to open the file for each build to re-add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add capabilities as follows: **[PlayerSettingsWSA Capabilities](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Capabilities)**

If a capability is not in the list you must build your project with IL2CPP in order to output an app package manifest named `Package.appxmanifest` and modify the XML by yourself.

#### In order to make things magically

You can write a method which have a `PostProcessBuildAttribute` attibute like so: **[Unity - Scripting API: PostProcessBuildAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html)** that will verify and add the XML tag if it not present in the  `Package.appxmanifest`.

Also you can create your custom build like that: **[Unity - Manual: Build Player Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html)** and add the same logic to verify and add the capability (an XML tag)

**Pseudo code:**

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;

public class MyBuildPostprocessor {
    [PostProcessBuildAttribute(1)]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject) {
         XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
         xmlDoc.Load($"{pathToBuiltProject}/{PROJECT NAME HERE}/Package.appxmanifest");
         // Find if the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability exists
         // add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability
    }
}
```

Comment: @MagnetMan Glad to helped you!